# Posul in Most of Eretz Yisroel Kosher within the walls of Yerushlayim

Tags: sukkah, riddle, eretz-yisrael

How is it possible to Make a Sukkah the same way and the same conditions but outside Yerushalayim it is not Kosher inside the walls of Yerushalayim it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there are a few answers so let me get started. Someone started saying the first one That is someone makes it in *Reshus Harabim*(public property) in Eretz Yisroel it would be problematic as it is stolen but since we know that Yerushlayim was נתחלקה לשבטים that is every on of the tribes owns part of it makes them partners and as the Marsha says on Sukkah סוכה כ''ז Sukkah of partners is Kosher.

The second answer is more involved it is from Hilchos *Negaim*. In Eretz Yisroel someone has a *Negah* on the wall of their Sukkah it has no Shiur of 7 by 7 that a Sukkah requires as it is supposed to be destroyed, but in Yerushalayim seeing as there is no *Tumas Negaim* it is Kosher to use.

A third answer would be something similar to the Negah answer, it is any city in Eretz Yisroel where most people worship idols and do the things required to make a city an *Ir Hanidachas* the Sukkah woud be Posul at it has no Shiur as it is supposed to be burnt but Yerushlayim can not become an *Ir Hanidachas* hence it is Kosher.

Comment: Getting out the Shnapps

Comment: There are more answers I do not have the patience to Type them up but feel free to Keep looking for more answers

Answer (score 0):

Get a big enough bamboo mat to cover the area of the Old City and rest it on the Old City walls. If you rest it on the outside of the Old City walls, it's not a good סכה; on the inside, it is (I suppose).

Sorry, best I could come up with.

Oh! Oh! Wait! Maybe something to do with אסורי הנאה? Can a סכה not be made out of אסורי הנאה perhaps? And then find something that's an אסור הנאה if it's outside ירושלים — perhaps מע״ש or something.... Just thinking aloud here, folks, don't mind me.